# Python and pytorch, fuctions of loss for segmentation without OOP classes

Tags: python, pytorch, image-segmentation, loss-function

I started studying machine learning. I need write 3 loss functions for pytorch segmentation NeuroNet. BCEloss, DiceLoss and FocalLoss, without using `nn.Modules`.
I wrote 2 functions, but I doubt it is right or not.
And I don't know how to write a function at all FocalLoss.

```
def dice_loss(y_pred, y_real):
    eps = 1e-8
    y_pred = torch.sigmoid(y_pred)    
    num = 2.*torch.sum((y_real*y_pred), (1,2,3)) + eps
    den = torch.sum( y_pred, (1,2,3)) + torch.sum(y_real, (1,2,3)) + eps 
    res = 1 - torch.mean(num/den)
    return res

def bce_loss(y_pred, y_real):
    y_pred = F.sigmoid(y_pred)
    y_pred = y_pred.clamp(min=0)
    loss = (y_pred - y_pred * y_real + torch.log(1+torch.exp(-torch.abs(y_pred)))).mean()

    return loss
```